# django server address invalid

Tags: python, django, windows, ip-address

I started Django development server from Windows 7 command line at http://0.0.0.0:8000 and the message was OK. But when I entered the address into my browser it returned ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID. What might be the problem?
Update:
this time I ran the server at http://127.0.0.1:8000 which is a default anyway and it gave me a whole lot of messages the last being 'UnicodeDecodeError: "utf-8" cant decode byte 0xcf in position 2: invalid continuation line'.
I opened the file of the error but search found no such byte in there. Now I am stuck. Any suggestions so far?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is the wildcard IPv4 address. It tells django to listen to *every* IP address on the local machine. It is not a valid destination address to connect to. You might want to try with either [http://127.0.0.0:8000](http://127.0.0.0:8000) (localhost) or *http:// ip-adress-of-your-computer /*

Comment: what address you enter in browser?

Answer (score 3):

I think, IP address 0.0.0.0 is a special address, which means default route, when used in terms of networking. I think you must use localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead. Just type route print command in your command prompt, it'll show you the routing table, where 0.0.0.0 will be present, which specifies default route.